# SQLite to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have the following line that errors on the import and I cannot work out why!

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (field1 VARCHAR, field2 VARCHAR, field3 VARCHAR, field4 VARCHAR, field5 VARCHAR, field6 INT, field7 VARCHAR);
```

This is an export of a SQLite dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide lengths for the VARCHAR type columns.

Use appropriate length for each VARCHAR column.

```
CREATE TABLE testtable 
(
  field1 VARCHAR(255), 
  field2 VARCHAR(255), 
  field3 VARCHAR(255), 
  field4 VARCHAR(255), 
  field5 VARCHAR(255), 
  field6 INT, 
  field7 VARCHAR(255)
);
```